# Python Multi Thread on separate script

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I have scripts which running new client into a new thread

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=loop_logic,args=(client1,))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=loop_logic,args=(client2,))
```

and they are always running to with while `True` condition

Let say my script is `server.py`

Then I want to make `client.py` to add new thread to `server.py` while it running so when I execute `client.py` it will add:

```
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=loop_logic,args=(client3,))
```

and so on.
What method I can use to do this ?

Comment: You will need some form of communication between the scripts, like pipes or sockets.

Comment: i learn about sockets today, any simple codes you can give me for the example to run a new thread from client? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class for both client and server, passing the reference to the server to each new client and addind a function for creating new clients to the server class. here is a very basic example

```
import threading

class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.chilren = []
        self.threads = []
    def NewChild(self, client_info):
        child = Client(self, client_info)  # self is a reference to the current server instance
        child_thread = threading.thread(target=child.run, args=(,))
        self.children.append(child)
        self.threads.append(child_thread)
        child_thread.start()
    def run(self):
        pass
        # Whatever server code should go here

class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, info): # info is a stand-in for arguments
        self.parent = parent
        self.info = info
    def run(self):
        self.parent.NewChild(other_info)
        # Any other processing too
```

In this example `logic_loop` is replaced by the `Client.run` method. Any processing done in that function would happen in `run` and any arguments would be passed into the class as the `info` argument